# Is it possible to alter a bool value by calling an extension method on the same variable in c#?

Tags: c#, boolean, extension-methods

In swift, it is possible to toggle a `Boolean` by simply calling `.toggle()` on the var.

```
var isVisible = false
isVisible.toggle()  // true
```

I wanted to create the same functionality in C#, so I wrote an extension method on 'bool'

```
public static class Utilities {
    public static void Toggle(this bool variable) {
        variable = !variable;
        //bool temp = variable;
        //variable = !temp;
    }
}
```

However, it does not work, and I suspect that it has to do with `bool` in C# being value types, where as they are reference types in swift.

Is there a way to implement the same toggle function in C#?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it by accepting the **`this`** `bool` object **by reference**:

```
public static class Utilities
{
    //-----------------------------vvv
    public static void Toggle(this ref bool variable)
    {
        variable = !variable;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool b1 = true;
        Console.WriteLine("before: " + b1);
        b1.Toggle();
        Console.WriteLine("after: " + b1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
before: True
after: False
```

**Note:** this feature is available only from C# 7.2. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods#:%7E:text=Beginning%20with%20C%23%207.2%2C%20you,of%20the%20struct%20being%20extended).